# How to set constraints in Xcode 8 in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout, constraints

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to set constraints in Xcode 8. I have set constraints in Xcode 6.2 now I update xcode 8 and my constraint are not working.

I have tried each thing which is on net but nothing help. I have also changed Opens in "Xcode 7.x" but not work. I am using custom tableview and it shows text as in the image.

[image]

Constraint screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you add screenshot of constraints which you have put and simulator screen shot with xcode 6.2

Comment: @Priyal I have used Add missing constraint in Xcode 6.2

Comment: Can you add screenshot of constraints, It will help.

Comment: I think you also need to provide code of your tableview's datasource and delegate, I think the tableviewcell's height might be "wrong". Because you have a margin to the top and bottom the label's height will be decreased, if the cell's height is too low

Comment: @Muju What's the height of your cell ?

Comment: @Priyal its 295.

Comment: There are two ways in which you can set cell height. Option 1 : Under TableView Height : https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDkvM.png
Option 2 : UiTableViewCell's Custom Height : https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnDCm.png
Which one are you using ?
OR are you setting it via code using heightForRowAtIndexPath Method ?

Comment: @Priyal I am using first option and I am not using method heightForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: can you implement heightForRowAtIndexPath method and return desired value from it.

Answer (score 0):

Select the controller size same as Xcode 6.2 in the storyboard.

Comment: its is custom Table View cell.